# Custom Middleware get_response not working

Tags: django

What I am trying to achieve is incase if the subdomain(tenant) is registered then it should display a different page else execute normally.

I am just trying to run django with a custom Middleware. As of now the get_response returns a 500 status while displaying the home page.

The exception below returns `'NoneType' object is not callable`

In case the user is a normal user and not a tenant, I wanted the app to run normally.

I've just started but the get_response function, which I suppose, is to show responses as executed by other middlewares later results in 500 status.

Any help trying to figure out, how I could use my custom middleware is appreciated.

```
class TenantMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):

        absolute_url = request.get_full_path()
        url = urlparse.urlparse(absolute_url)
        print absolute_url
        print url

        subdomain = url.hostname.split(".") if url.hostname else None
        if subdomain and subdomain != 'affectlab' :
            if 'subdomain' not in request.session:
                print "I am here"
                tenant=map(lambda x : x[0],(list(profiles.models.Tenant.objects.filter(name=subdomain).values_list('id'))))
                if tenant:
                    request.session['tenant'] = int(tenant[0])
                    request.session['subdomain'] = subdomain.strip()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")

                else:
                    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                    response.status_code = 404
                    return response
            else:
                if request.session['subdomain'] == subdomain:
                    return self.get_response(request)
                else:

                    tenant = map(lambda x: x[0],(list(profiles.models.Tenant.objects.filter(name=subdomain)).values_list('id')))
                    if tenant:
                        request.session['tenant'] = int(tenant[0])
                        request.session['subdomain'] = subdomain.strip()
                        response = logout(request)  # ,next_page=reverse("/"))
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")
                    else:
                        response = render_to_response('404.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                        response.status_code = 404
                        return response
        else:
            try :

                response = self.get_response(request)
            except Exception as e:
                print e.message
            return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using Django1.10 it seems I have to use MIDDLEWARE instead of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in the settings file.

Just had to use MIDDLEWARE.

We could also write it this way.

```
class TenantMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self,get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response    

    def __call__(self, request):

        absolute_url = request.get_full_path()
        url = urlparse.urlparse(absolute_url)
        print absolute_url
        print url

        subdomain = url.hostname.split(".") if url.hostname else None
        if subdomain and subdomain != 'affectlab' :
            if 'subdomain' not in request.session:
                print "I am here"
                tenant=map(lambda x : x[0],(list(profiles.models.Tenant.objects.filter(name=subdomain).values_list('id'))))
                if tenant:
                    request.session['tenant'] = int(tenant[0])
                    request.session['subdomain'] = subdomain.strip()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")

                else:
                    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                    response.status_code = 404
                    return response
            else:
                if request.session['subdomain'] == subdomain:
                    return self.get_response(request)
                else:

                    tenant = map(lambda x: x[0],(list(profiles.models.Tenant.objects.filter(name=subdomain)).values_list('id')))
                    if tenant:
                        request.session['tenant'] = int(tenant[0])
                        request.session['subdomain'] = subdomain.strip()
                        response = logout(request)  # ,next_page=reverse("/"))
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")
                    else:
                        response = render_to_response('404.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                        response.status_code = 404
                        return response
        else:
            try :

                response = self.get_response(request)
            except Exception as e:
                print e.message1
            return response
```